# Creation of a secure connection between the client and the server based on certificates

Tags: tls1.2, tcpclient, x509certificate2, tcpserver

There is an attempt to create a client-server application using certificates.
Certificates are created with the following commands in powerShell:
**creating a master certificate**
`$bigCert = New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName AroganitSaveCityCA -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(50)`
**transfers the certificate to trusted**
`$store = get-item Cert:\LocalMachine\Root $store.Open("ReadWrite") $store.Add($bigCert) $store.Close()`
**server certificate**
`$server = New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName AroganitSaveCity -Signer $bigCert -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(50)`
**client certificate**
$client= New-SelfSignedCertificate -CertStoreLocation cert:\LocalMachine\My -DnsName AroganitSaveCityClient -Signer $bigCert -NotAfter (Get-Date).AddYears(50)

When I try to connect and validate the certificate, I get the error:
**System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: 'The remote certificate is invalid based on authentication results.'**

**TcpServer code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Uniframe.Infrastructure.DataStore.Internal;
using Uniframe.Infrastructure.Logging;
using Uniframe.Notification.Library.PITV.Services;
using Uniframe.Notification.Tls12Tcp;

namespace Uniframe.Notification.Library.PITV.Servers.TCP
{
    public class PitvTcpServer
    {
        private Tls12TcpServer _server;
        private static X509Certificate2 _certificate;
        private static X509Certificate2 _mainCertificate;
        private static ILogger _logger;
        private readonly RequestHandler _requestHandler;
        private readonly TimeSpan _waitTime;
        private IPAddress _hostIpAddress;
        private int _hostPort;
        private bool _isStoping;

        public PitvTcpServer(IPAddress hostIpAddress, int hostPort, string thumbPrint, ILogger logger, IPitvAnswerProvider pitvAnswerProvider)
        {
            _hostIpAddress = hostIpAddress;
            _hostPort = hostPort;
            _waitTime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            _logger = logger;

            try
            {
               _certificate = GetCertificate(thumbPrint);
                var chain = X509Chain.Create();
                chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
                chain.ChainPolicy.VerificationFlags = X509VerificationFlags.IgnoreWrongUsage;
                if (!chain.Build(_certificate))
                {
                    _logger.Warn("Проблема с определением цепочки сертификата");
                }

                foreach (var element in chain.ChainElements)
                {
                    if (element.Certificate.Thumbprint == "4E0FD9A23D6C0B9667B87208B335FBF5D222AA42")
                    {
                        _mainCertificate = element.Certificate;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (_mainCertificate == null)
                {
                    _logger.Warn("Не удалось определить главный сертификат по цепочки");
                }
                _logger.Info("Сертификат успешно найден");
                //_certificate = FindCertificate("5D4E76A518086FA416698BF3151D2DE8D1AED7A6");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error(ex, "Не удалось найти сертификат");
                return;
            }

            _requestHandler = new RequestHandler(logger, pitvAnswerProvider);
        }

        public void Start() => StartListening();

        private void StartListening()
        {
            _isStoping = false;
            _server = new Tls12TcpServer(_logger, _hostIpAddress, _hostPort, _certificate, OnServerConnectionAvailable, CheckCertificate);            
            _server.StartListening();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _isStoping = true;
            StopListening();
        }

        private void StopListening()
        {
            _server.StopListening();
            _server?.Dispose();
        }

        private void OnServerConnectionAvailable(object sender, SecureConnectionResults args)
        {
            if (args.AsyncException != null)
            {
                _logger.Info(args.AsyncException.ToString());
                return;
            }

            SslStream stream = args.SecureStream;

            _logger.Info($"Получено защищенное соединение");

            try
            {
                var dataStream = false;

                do
                {
                    var requestLength = 0;

                    dataStream = ReadRequestLength(stream, ref requestLength);

                    if (dataStream && requestLength > 0)
                    {
                        var request = string.Empty;

                        dataStream = ReadRequest(stream, requestLength, ref request);

                        if (dataStream)
                        {
                            ProcessRequest(stream, request);
                        }
                    }
                }
                while (dataStream);

                _logger.Warn($"Поток завершен");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Warn(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                stream.Close();
            }

            if (!_isStoping)
            {
                StopListening();
                StartListening();
            }
        }

        private bool ReadRequestLength(SslStream stream, ref int length)
        {
            var lengthBuffer = new byte[4];

            if (!WaitRead(stream, lengthBuffer))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
                Array.Reverse(lengthBuffer);

            length = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBuffer, 0);

            return true;
        }

        private bool ReadRequest(SslStream stream, int length, ref string request)
        {
            var requestBuffer = new byte[length];

            if (!WaitRead(stream, requestBuffer))
            {
                return false;
            }

            request = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(requestBuffer);

            return true;
        }

        private bool WaitRead(SslStream stream, byte[] buffer)
        {
            int bytes = 0;
            DateTime endWait = DateTime.Now + _waitTime;

            while (bytes == 0)
            {
                bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                if (DateTime.Now >= endWait)
                {
                    _logger.Warn($"Подключение бездействует {_waitTime.TotalMinutes} минут");
                    return false;
                }
            }

            stream.Flush();

            return true;
        }

        private void WriteResponse(SslStream stream, string response)
        {
            stream.Flush();
            var responseArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);
            var length = BitConverter.GetBytes(responseArray.Length);
            if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(length);

            stream.Write(length);
            stream.Write(responseArray);
        }

        private void ProcessRequest(SslStream stream, string request)
        {
            try
            {
                if (_requestHandler.TryParseRequest(request, out var command))
                {
                    _logger.Debug($"Получен запрос: {command}" + Environment.NewLine + request);

                    string response = _requestHandler.GetResponse(command, request).Result;

                    WriteResponse(stream, response);

                    _logger.Debug($"Сервер отправил: '{response}'");
                }
                else
                {
                    _logger.Warn($"Не удалось распознать запрос {request}");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(ex, "Не удалось отправить ответ на запрос");
            }
        }

        private static bool CheckCertificate(
            object sender,
            X509Certificate certificate,
            X509Chain chain,
            SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors && sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None)
            {
                _logger.Warn($"Ошибка политики шифрования {sslPolicyErrors}");
                return false;
            }

            if (certificate == null)
            {
                _logger.Warn($"Клиент не передал сертификат.");
                return false;
            }

            if (chain == null)
            {
                _logger.Warn("Не указана цепочка доверия.");
                return false;
            }

            if (!chain.ChainElements.Cast<X509ChainElement>()
                .Any(x => x.Certificate.Thumbprint == _mainCertificate.Thumbprint))
            {
                _logger.Warn("Цепочка сертификатов клиента не позволяет определить родительский сертификат");
            }

            _logger.Info("Сертификат клиента прошел проверку");
            return true;
        }

        private X509Certificate2 FindCertificate(string fileName) => new X509Certificate2(fileName);

        private X509Certificate2 GetCertificate(string thumbPrint)
        {
            X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbPrint, false);
            certStore.Close();

            return certCollection.OfType<X509Certificate2>().FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

**Error happens on callback**

```
    if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors && sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None)
            {
                _logger.Warn($"Ошибка политики шифрования {sslPolicyErrors}");
                return false;
            }
```

**TcpService**

```
System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Uniframe.Infrastructure.DataStore;
using Uniframe.Infrastructure.Logging;
using Uniframe.Notification.Library.PITV.Servers.TCP;
using Uniframe.Notification.Library.PITV.Services;
using Uniframe.Notification.Library.PITV.Storage;
using Uniframe.Platform.Api;

namespace Uniframe.Service.PITV.Services
{
    internal class PitvTcpService
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly PitvTcpServer _server;
        private readonly IPAddress _hostIpAddress;
        private readonly int _hostPort;
        private readonly IRepository _repository;

        public PitvTcpService(ILogger logger, IRepository repository)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _repository = repository;
            IPitvAnswerProvider pitvAnswerProvider
                = new PitvAnswerProvider(_logger, repository/*, config.Systems?.ToList() ?? new List<Guid>()*/);

            _hostIpAddress = IPAddress.Parse(GetConfigValue(PITVStaticData.PITVServerAddress.Id).Result);
            _hostPort = int.Parse(GetConfigValue(PITVStaticData.PITVServerPort.Id).Result);
            var config = GetConfiguration();
            _server = new PitvTcpServer(_hostIpAddress, _hostPort, config.CertificateThumbPrint, _logger, pitvAnswerProvider);
        }
        
        private PitvConfiguration GetConfiguration()
        {
            return new PitvConfiguration()
            {
                CertificateThumbPrint = "9e753e2a85f1e7871bedb2396fda25ec3c27d6a4",
                IpAddress = _hostIpAddress.ToString(),
                Port = _hostPort,
            };
        }
        
        public void Start()
        {
                _server.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _server.Stop();            
        }
        private async Task<string> GetConfigValue(Guid templateId)
        {
            try
            {
                return await _repository.QueryAsync(new GetSettingsByKey(templateId));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.Error(ex, $"Ошибка при запросе параметра конфигурации по ключу {templateId}");
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Tls12TcpServer**

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Uniframe.Infrastructure.Logging;

namespace Uniframe.Notification.Tls12Tcp
{   
    public class Tls12TcpServer
    {
        X509Certificate2 _serverCert;
        RemoteCertificateValidationCallback _certValidationCallback;
        SecureConnectionResultsCallback _connectionCallback;
        AsyncCallback onAcceptConnection;
        AsyncCallback onAuthenticateAsServer;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        bool _started;
        int _disposed;

        IPAddress _hostIpAddress;
        int _listenPort;

        TcpListener _listener;

        public Tls12TcpServer(ILogger logger,
            IPAddress hostIpAddress,
            int listenPort,
            X509Certificate2 serverCertificate,
            SecureConnectionResultsCallback callback)
            : this(logger, hostIpAddress, listenPort, serverCertificate, callback, null)
        { }

        public Tls12TcpServer(ILogger logger,
            IPAddress hostIpAddress,
            int listenPort,
            X509Certificate2 serverCertificate,
            SecureConnectionResultsCallback callback,
            RemoteCertificateValidationCallback certValidationCallback)
        {
            if (listenPort < 0 || listenPort > UInt16.MaxValue)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("listenPort");

            _serverCert = serverCertificate ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("serverCertificate");
            _connectionCallback = callback ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("callback");

            onAcceptConnection = new AsyncCallback(OnAcceptConnection);
            onAuthenticateAsServer = new AsyncCallback(OnAuthenticateAsServer);

            _certValidationCallback = certValidationCallback;
            _hostIpAddress = hostIpAddress;
            _listenPort = listenPort;
            _disposed = 0;
            CheckCertifcateRevocation = false;
            ClientCertificateRequired = true;

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
            _logger = logger;
        }

        ~Tls12TcpServer()
        {
            Dispose();
        }

        public SslProtocols SslProtocols { get; set; }

        public bool CheckCertifcateRevocation { get; set; }

        public bool ClientCertificateRequired { get; set; }

        public void StartListening()
        {
            if (_started)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Сервер уже запущен...");

            IPEndPoint localIP;

            if (_listener == null)
            {
                localIP = new IPEndPoint(_hostIpAddress, _listenPort);
                _logger.Info($"Защищенный tcp сервер запущен на {localIP}");
                _listener = new TcpListener(localIP);
            }

            if (_listener != null)
            {
                _listener.Start();
                _listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(onAcceptConnection, _listener);
            }

            _started = true;
        }

        public void StopListening()
        {
            if (!_started)
                return;
            _started = false;

            if (_listener != null)
                _listener.Stop();
        }

        void OnAcceptConnection(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            _logger.Info("OnAcceptConnection");
            TcpListener listener = result.AsyncState as TcpListener;
            TcpClient client = null;
            SslStream sslStream = null;

            try
            {
                if (_started)
                {
                    //start accepting the next connection...
                    listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(onAcceptConnection, listener);
                }
                else
                {
                    //someone called Stop() - don't call EndAcceptTcpClient because
                    //it will throw an ObjectDisposedException
                    return;
                }

                //complete the last operation...
                client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(result);

                bool leaveStreamOpen = false;//close the socket when done

                if (_certValidationCallback != null)
                    sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), leaveStreamOpen, _certValidationCallback);
                else
                    sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), leaveStreamOpen);

                sslStream.BeginAuthenticateAsServer(_serverCert,
                    ClientCertificateRequired,
                    SslProtocols,
                    CheckCertifcateRevocation,//CheckCertifcateRevocation
                    onAuthenticateAsServer,
                    sslStream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (sslStream != null)
                {
                    sslStream.Dispose();
                    sslStream = null;
                }
                _connectionCallback(this, new SecureConnectionResults(ex));
            }
        }

        void OnAuthenticateAsServer(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            SslStream sslStream = null;

            try
            {
                sslStream = result.AsyncState as SslStream;
                sslStream.EndAuthenticateAsServer(result);

                _connectionCallback(this, new SecureConnectionResults(sslStream));
            }
            catch (AuthenticationException ex)
            {
                _logger.Error("Ошибка авторизации: ", ex);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (sslStream != null)
                {
                    sslStream.Dispose();
                    sslStream = null;
                }

                _connectionCallback(this, new SecureConnectionResults(ex));
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref _disposed) == 1)
            {
                _listener?.Stop();
                _listener = null;

                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Tls12TcpClient**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Uniframe.Notification.Tls12Tcp
{
    public class Tls12TcpClient
    {
        X509CertificateCollection _clientCertificates;
        RemoteCertificateValidationCallback _certValidationCallback;
        SecureConnectionResultsCallback _connectionCallback;

        AsyncCallback _onConnected;
        AsyncCallback _onAuthenticateAsClient;

        TcpClient _client;

        IPEndPoint _remoteEndPoint;

        SslProtocols _protocols;

        int _disposed;

        private const string ClientThumbPrint = "f00d3afbfbf2c5a153f0b30c6e37a2c8aeabba4a";

        public Tls12TcpClient(SecureConnectionResultsCallback callback)
            : this(callback, null, SslProtocols.Tls12)
        {
        }

        public Tls12TcpClient(SecureConnectionResultsCallback callback,
            RemoteCertificateValidationCallback certValidationCallback)
            : this(callback, certValidationCallback, SslProtocols.Tls12)
        {
        }

        public Tls12TcpClient(SecureConnectionResultsCallback callback,
            RemoteCertificateValidationCallback certValidationCallback,
            SslProtocols sslProtocols)
        {
            _certValidationCallback = certValidationCallback;
            _connectionCallback = callback ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("callback");

            _onAuthenticateAsClient = new AsyncCallback(OnAuthenticateAsClient);

            _protocols = sslProtocols;

            _disposed = 0;
        }

        ~Tls12TcpClient()
        {
            Dispose();
        }

        public bool CheckCertificateRevocation { get; set; }

        public void StartConnecting(IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint)
        {
            StartConnecting(remoteEndPoint, GetCertificate(ClientThumbPrint));
        }

        public void StartConnecting(IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint,
            X509Certificate2Collection clientCertificates)
        {
            if (remoteEndPoint == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("remoteEndPoint");

            Console.WriteLine("Client connecting to: {0}", remoteEndPoint);

            _clientCertificates = clientCertificates;
            _remoteEndPoint = remoteEndPoint;

            if (_client != null)
                _client.Close();

            _client = new TcpClient();
            _client.Connect(remoteEndPoint);

            OnConnected();
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            Dispose();
        }

        void OnConnected()
        {
            SslStream sslStream = null;

            try
            {
                bool leaveStreamOpen = false;//close the socket when done

                if (_certValidationCallback != null)
                    sslStream = new SslStream(_client.GetStream(), leaveStreamOpen, _certValidationCallback);
                else
                    sslStream = new SslStream(_client.GetStream(), leaveStreamOpen);

                //sslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync  не работает
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient($"{_remoteEndPoint.Address}:{_remoteEndPoint.Port}",
                   _clientCertificates,
                   _protocols,
                   false);

                Console.WriteLine("Прошла аутентификация клиента");

                _connectionCallback(this, new SecureConnectionResults(sslStream));

                //_connectionCallback(this, new SecureConnectionResults(sslStream));

                //sslStream.BeginAuthenticateAsClient(
                //    _remoteHostName,
                //    _clientCertificates,
                //    _protocols,
                //    false,
                //    _onAuthenticateAsClient,
                //    sslStream);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (sslStream != null)
                {
                    sslStream.Dispose();
                    sslStream = null;
                }

                _connectionCallback(this, new SecureConnectionResults(ex));
            }
        }

        private static TimeSpan _waitTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);

        void OnAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            SslStream sslStream = null;

            try
            {
                sslStream = result.AsyncState as SslStream;
                sslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(result);

                _connectionCallback(this, new SecureConnectionResults(sslStream));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (sslStream != null)
                {
                    sslStream.Dispose();
                    sslStream = null;
                }

                _connectionCallback(this, new SecureConnectionResults(ex));
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref _disposed) == 1)
            {
                if (_client != null)
                {
                    _client.Close();
                    _client = null;
                }
                GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            }
        }

        private X509Certificate2Collection GetCertificate(string thumbPrint)
        {
            X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(
                X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbPrint, false);
            certStore.Close();

            return certCollection;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know where to look, because the result is returned by a third-party assembly